# How do you accept one nested attribute, when that attribute is associated via has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have the following model setup. I have Match and Game. Match has_many :games, and Match accepts_nested_attributes_for :games. :games_attributes is attr_accessible by all members. My problem is, fields_for is not generating the correct form, so Match is not accepting the nested attributes for games. Here is my form code:

```
<%= form_for [@tournament, match], url: tournament_match_path(@tournament, match) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for match.games.last do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.hidden_field :winner_id, value: 1 %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Win Game", class: "actionButton activeAction" %>
<% end %>
```

The code generated by this is:

```
<form id="edit_match_1" class="edit_match" method="post" action="/tournaments/1/matches/1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"> <!-- rails stuff here --></div>
  <input id="match_game_winner_id" type="hidden" value="1" name="match[game][winner_id]">
  <input class="actionButton activeAction" type="submit" value="Win Game" name="commit">
</form>
```

As you can see, the name of match_game_winner_id is incorrect. The name is match[game][winner_id], but the name should be match[games_attributes][0][winner_id]. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I suspect the issue is because you're working with nested resources inside of other nested resources. I see why `tournaments/:id/matches/:id/games` makes sense, but I suspect you'll have some trouble getting the form builder to cooperate. I say that because I don't see anything wrong with your code but you're right that the output generated is incorrect.

Comment: I don't think so. I think the problem arises from passing a singular resource to f.fields_for. If I replace `f.fields_for match.games.last` with `f.fields_for :games` I get the correct output.

Comment: Ok I solved the problem. It is weird, and I have no idea why this worked, but I replaced `f.fields_for match.games.last` with f.fields_for :games, :last`.

Comment: Oh yes, that's right! Fields for expects a symbol, not an object. I think it then calls the symbol passed as a method against the object for the parent form. You should write up your findings as an answer to this question and then select your answer so it shows up as "solved" and will help more people in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this question on my own, and would like to share my findings to help others in a similar situation. As Andrew said in the comments, fields_for expects a symbol, so in order to get the last game, I need to pass a list of symbols corresponding to the methods that get the last game. My form ended up looking like this:

```
<%= form_for [@tournament, match], url: tournament_match_path(@tournament, match) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :games, :last do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.hidden_field :winner_id, value: 1 %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Win Game", class: "actionButton activeAction" %>
<% end %>
```